# Why can't USART in synchronous mode be full duplex?

Tags: uart

I have read in many websites (for example [Difference between USART and UART](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-usart-and-uart/) and [Difference between USART and UART](https://www.javatpoint.com/usart-vs-uart)) that USART operates in half-duplex mode and UART operates in full-duplex, but they never explain why.

I don't understand what makes it not possible for USART in synchronous mode to operate in full-duplex, given that there two pins available for data, just like in UART or SPI and they can operate in full-duplex.

Comment: I would not trust either of those web pages you linked to. First of all, either one of them plagarized the other, or else they both plagarized some other source. I can tell it's plagarism because both spout nearly the same meaningless, gobbledygook. (E.g., "USART is fit for directing the entire procedure in the switch request where sequential information is infused...") My guess is that the author does not know the difference between what the hardware is capable of doing, and the ways in which certain well-known applications make use of the hardware. If in doubt, consult the reference manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terms USART and UART are very broad and can mean different things to different applications.

Generally speaking the "synchronous" part ('S') means that a clock signal is sent along with the data to keep everything synchronised.

Whereas the "asynchronous" operation means the far end has to recover the clock from the data signal, for UART by guessing based on knowing the approximate baud rate.

---

Now if we are talking simple 8N1 or similar serial interfaces such as underly RS232 etc, then you may only have two wires available for data transfer.

For synchronous operation, requiring sending the clock uses up one of these wires. The other is then used for data. This means you cannot both transmit and receive at the same time in synchronous mode hence half-duplex. For example the Rx wire could be used to send the clock, and the Tx wire used bidirectionally for sending and receiving data.

For asynchronous mode, you don't need the clock so one wire can be used for transmit, the other for receive allowing full duplex.

In other applications you can have a different number of wires. For example ATMega MCUs provide a third wire for clock in syncronous mode. This means that full duplex synchronous operation is perfectly possible in such an application because we now have an extra wire to carry the clock.

Comment: How are the Tx clock and the Rx clock syncronized if there is significant phase delay over a long transmission path?

Comment: @RussellH have each end latch data on opposite clock edges, and keep the clock rate low enough that the round trip propagation time plus other necessary delays fit within a half-cycle. It's not perfect but it's simple, and in many cases it works just fine.

Comment: @RussellH It has not really changed much from the MC6850 ACIA days. In the ATmega the external clock is a bit clock, RXD is sampled at opposite edge than TXD is updated, and the clock edge polarity is selectable. That will limit the transmission path length - but synchronous is rarely used over long links anyway.

Comment: @Justme: So the observation that USARTs operate half duplex has some validity for long lines!

Comment: @RussellH It's not specific to USART, as it is a generic synchronous communication problem present in SPI too. So in theory, USART or SPI should go equally far at equally high speeds, and yes, that's why synchronous comms are not used over very long lines. But still you cam use both synchronous USART and SPI between two PCBs in same case at equally high lengths and data rates.